# Named router-outlet inside module - Path match but content doesn't load

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-auxiliary-routes

I have a lazy loaded module which includes named router-outlet (auxiliary routes). I'm not able to target content into this router. The path match and I can see it in the url but the content doesn't appear.

Here is a code example:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cxvlqz?file=src/app/modules/submod/submod.component.ts)

==== UPDATE

The code is fixed.

Usage:

1. click on the "LOAD SUBMODULE" link
2. submodule loads
3. click on any lines above of "SUBMOD loaded" title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a router outlet inside a component the child routes needs be declared as children for the parent route.

This is how your submod routes should look like

```js
{
  path: '',
  component: SubmodComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'toloadin', outlet: 'suboutlet', component: ToLoadinComponent },
  ],
}
```

Comment: I think 1 declaration with named outlet is enought

Comment: with or without outlet, toloadin path needs to be inside children array but in this case yes only one is enough, updated the answer